# How to add a rate limit to a Resque queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

So I have a Resque worker that calls an API, the issue is the API has a rate limit of 2 requests per second.

Is there a way to add a delay between each job processed in a specific queue?

P.S. the queue could have thousands of pending jobs.

Comment: Why not just sleep for a given amount of time at the end of the process?

Comment: You're right! so stupid from me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per my comment, I'd recommend just performing a `sleep` for a given number of seconds at the end of each Resque `process` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sleep for a given amount of time at the end of the process?  Well, perhaps you want your resque worker to be doing something useful instead.  In CPU time, half a second is a lot of time - you could have done something useful there, like process a job from another queue that's not rate limited.

I have this same problem myself, so I'm motivated to find a solution.  It seems like there are two easy-ish ways to do it.  The first idea is to use resque scheduler and pre-compute the time to run the job at before inserting it.  This seems error-prone to me.  The second is to use a gem like https://github.com/flyerhzm/resque-restriction (disclaimer: just found it through some googling. haven't used it yet) and rate-limit as you pull jobs *off* the queue.  Seems like a robust solution in theory.  Note that if you can't execute the job yet, it never comes off the queue, so you'll pull something else instead - much more efficient use of your workers.